# PowerShell PKI module not available

Tags: powershell

Executing `PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable`, it provides my all of available modules, but I'm unable to find the PKI module. How can I add it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [`PSPKI` module](https://github.com/Crypt32/PSPKI). This is an alternative third party module, and includes different commands from `PKI`.

If you're using a modern version (PSv5 +) you can use `Install-Module -Name PSPKI` to install the module, if not you will need to download and copy the module to your modules folder.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: This isn't the same module as `PKI`. See `Get-Command -module PKI` vs `Get-Command -module PSPKI`